# C# MVC Interface error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, interface

I have tried to implement interfaces and am experiencing difficulty with the following error:

I want the code to be layered and am trying to use good practices. I also want to start using interfaces and experiment more with new code. Hope I can get this to work.

I know there are articles about this error on SO and I have explored them. Some are confusing for me to implement as I am a beginner with Interfaces and NuGet Packages. I hope my Question can develop a simple Answer with a full example or correction to my classes that I can take and use as a base for all my future development.

```
 No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +113
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +232
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +6
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +55

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'UniStock.Controllers.InventoryController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +178
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +77
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +66
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +191
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

**Here are my classes:**

**Controller:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using UniStock.Services.ExportImport;


namespace UniStock.Controllers
{
    public partial class InventoryController : Controller
    {
        #region Fields

        private readonly IImportManager _importService;

        #endregion

        #region Constructors


        public InventoryController(IImportManager importService)
        {
            this._importService = importService;
        }

        #endregion


        public ActionResult StockItems()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ImportNewCodes()
        {
            var model = new UniStock.Models.InventoryModel();

            return PartialView(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult ImportNewCodesPost(FormCollection form)
        {
            try
            {
                var file = Request.Files["excelFile"];
                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    string filepath = _importService.ImportNewCodes(file.InputStream);

                    return Json(new
                    {
                        success = false,
                        message = filepath
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    return Json(new
                    {
                        success = false,
                        message = "file not selected"
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new
                {
                    success = false,
                    message = "ImportNewCodesPost: " + ex.Message
                });
            }

            return Json(new
            {
                success = false,
                message = "Email is invalid"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace UniStock.Models
{
    public partial class InventoryModel
    {
        public InventoryModel()
        {
        }

        public int InventoryID { get; set; }

        public string Code { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string Style { get; set; }

        public string SytleColour { get; set; }

        public string ColourCode { get; set; }

        public string ColourName { get; set; }

        public string Size { get; set; }

        public string BarCode { get; set; }

        public bool? Active { get; set; }

        public bool? Deleted { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }

        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Inventory Service:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UniStock.Services.Inventory
{
    public partial class InventoryService
    {
        public InventoryService() { }
    }
}
```

**Inventory Service Interface:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Services.Inventory
{
    public partial interface IInventoryService
    {
    }
}
```

**Import Service:**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

using OfficeOpenXml;

using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Configuration;

using Services.Inventory;

namespace UniStock.Services.ExportImport
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Import manager
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ImportManager : IImportManager
    {
        #region Fields

        private readonly IInventoryService  _inventoryService;

        #endregion

        #region Ctor

        public ImportManager(IInventoryService inventoryService)
        {
            this._inventoryService = inventoryService;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Utilities

        protected virtual int GetColumnIndex(string[] properties, string columnName)
        {
            if (properties == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("properties");

            if (columnName == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("columnName");

            for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
                if (properties[i].Equals(columnName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    return i + 1; //excel indexes start from 1
            return 0;
        }

        protected virtual string ConvertColumnToString(object columnValue)
        {
            if (columnValue == null)
                return null;

            return Convert.ToString(columnValue);
        }

        protected virtual string GetMimeTypeFromFilePath(string filePath)
        {
            //var mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filePath);

            ////little hack here because MimeMapping does not contain all mappings (e.g. PNG)
            //if (mimeType == "application/octet-stream")
            //    mimeType = "image/jpeg";

            //return mimeType;

            return "";
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        public DataTable LoadFromExcelFile(string filePath)
        {
            String excelConnString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0\"", filePath);
            //Create Connection to Excel work book 
            using (OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnString))
            {
                //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel - you can query the sheet as if it were a sql table effectively
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [SKU],[0-199],[200-499],[500-999],[1000+] from [Sheet1$]", excelConnection))
                {
                    excelConnection.Open();
                    using (OleDbDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        DataTable myData = new DataTable();
                        myData.Load(dReader);
                        return myData;
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }


        public virtual string ImportNewCodes(Stream stream)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(stream))
                {
                    //get the first worksheet in the workbook
                    var worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();
                    if (worksheet == null)
                        return "No worksheet found";

                    return "file accessed";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**Import Service Interface:**

```
using System.IO;

namespace UniStock.Services.ExportImport
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Import manager interface
    /// </summary>
    public partial interface IImportManager
    {

        string ImportNewCodes(Stream stream);


    }
}
```

Comment: The framework is trying to create the controller, but it doesn't appear Dependency Injection is setup?  Without that, it expects an empty constructor on the controller, but your controller has a parameter.  So either Di isn't setup, or if it is, this interface/type may not be mapped correctly...

Comment: Can you assist me with setting up this Dependency injection?  I am an absolute new bee to this :/

Comment: Which Dependency Injection framework you are going to use Unity or Ninject , I have an article on Setting up Dependency Injection using Unity Framework with ASP.NET MVC. URL : - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1199400/Dependency-Injection-using-Unity-Framework-with-AS

Comment: I'm currently experimenting with Autofac. Already half way through into implementation. If it does not workout, then I'll give your article a try. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Yes Saineshwar's example is one of many already available online - a lot of the Dependency Injection Framework already have integration projects ready to go so that you can incorporate DI into ASP.NET MVC with very little work, so look for that also on Nuget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YAYYY!!!! :)

So I followed the instructions using this link > https://levelnis.co.uk/blog/dependency-injection-with-autofac#ck_modal

It uses Autofac to inject dependencies, if I have that correct.

After implementing Autofac, my project now works with 1 parameter constructor and Interfaces are called as normal :)